# There is a problem with my web-scraping project

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my code

```
property_prices = []
base_url = 'https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Aurangabad'

for tag in price_link:
    property_prices.append(base_url + tag['href'])
    
property_prices
```

This is the error i am getting

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_56/3661987329.py in <module>
      3 
      4 for tag in price_link:
----> 5     property_prices.append(base_url + tag['href'])
      6 
      7 property_prices

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1517         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the Tag,
   1518         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
-> 1519         return self.attrs[key]
   1520 
   1521     def __iter__(self):

KeyError: 'href'
```

Please help

I am new to this so i am bit confused while creating a project on web scraping

Comment: 'href' is missing in tag for that element in  'price_link'. use if 'href' in tag: before that line

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as it is now, your code is not reproducible. How do you expect to be helped? Where did you define `price_link` array, and what does it look like? What data are you looking for from what specific url, and in what format?